# Magento 2 Blank Theme: How to reduce the height of Navigation, header and top links?

Tags: magento2, css, less

I want to reduce the height of the top sections (navigation, logo, search and top links) in the default Magento Blank theme but I cannot figure out how to do this.

I have created _extend.less and _navigation_extend.less in theme/web/css/source

In _extend.less:

```
@import '_navigation_extend.less';
```

In _navigation_extend.less I have tried many variations on code, I can get the coloured bar to be smaller with the following but the text remains the same height:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {

.navigation {
    height: 30px;
}
```

}

The text in the navigation bar still stays at 53px no matter what I do. I think it's linked to the ul but I've tried various versions of the following but I can't get it smaller:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {

.navigation {
    height: 30px;
}

.ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

}

Can anyone help me reduce the depth of these three sections? (I appreciate I haven't shown what I have done so far for the other two sections but help would be appreciated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this by adding the following code to my custom theme. Hopefully this will help others trying to do the same.

vendor/theme/web/css/source/_extend.less

```
@import '_extend-custom.less';
@import '_navigation_extend.less';
```

vendor/theme/web/css/source/_extend-custom.less

```
//
// Desktop
// _______________________________________________

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {

    // Make the very top bar smaller
    // Comes from magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less
    .page-header {
        .header.panel {
            &:extend(.abs-add-clearfix-desktop all);
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            padding-top: 5px;
        }
    }

    //Make the space required for the search box a smaller depth
    .block-search .control {
        border-top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    // Make the logo smaller
    .logo {
        margin: 0;

        img {
            max-height: inherit;
        }
    }

    // Remove the space above the header on the desktop to make the bar thinner
    // Comes from magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less
    .header {
        &.content {
            &:extend(.abs-add-clearfix-desktop all);
            padding: 5px @indent__base 0;
        }
    }

    // Reduce the height of the navigation bar
    .navigation {
        height: 30px;
    }

}
```

vendor/theme/web/css/source/_navigation_extend.less

```
//
//  Desktop navigation
//  ---

// Reduce the height of the navigation bar from the standard 53px
@navigation-desktop-level0-item__line-height: 30px;
```