# Header customization ( Container Height )

Tags: magento2.3.4

I'm using a custom theme, i would like to reduce the height of the mega menu container.
Could you please help me out ?

Please find the attached image. [image: header image ( screenshot)]

Comment: you add `max-height` css  in your nav-sections

Comment: could you please specify which file ?

Comment: you create any custom css  ??? If yes is your custom css add that file

Comment: no, i didnt create any custom css, however, this custom theme have a lot of header options.i have found out that these header files are inside pub folder, not app folder. the files inside the header folder are : element_less.css, _variable_less.css, header-styles.css, header-styles-less.css and variables.xml

Comment: any header file bottom add css in `<style></style>` tag

Comment: no, i didnt create any custom css, however, this custom theme have a lot of header options.i have found out that these header files are inside pub folder, not app folder. the files inside the header folder are : element_less.css, _variable_less.css, header-styles.css, header-styles-less.css and variables.xml

Comment: ny header file bottom add css in <style></style> tag ?what code to be added in btw, sorry im all new to this

Comment: any your .phtml file

Comment: i found mega menu in app\code\Codazon\MegaMenu\view\frontend\templates, but none of them have height specified.

Comment: mega menu inspect element and find the class and add the `max-height`  and check ..

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/172286/85907

Answer (score 0):

You can add your CSS in  your custom themes CSS/less files,

Or you can create a new CSS file.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Here is exact css to reduce height of megamenu nav container. You can check your website header-style-01 or header-style-03 or header-style-03

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.header-style-03 .panel.header .header-panel-bottom {height:45px !important;}
}
</style>
```

Comment: i have posted an answer, please find the code and refer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
.page-header .sticky-menu.active .header.panel .header-panel-bottom{margin:0}.page-header .sticky-menu.active .cdz-dropdown .cdz-dd-content{top:100%}.page-header .sticky-menu.active .cdz-vertical-menu .groupmenu{margin-bottom:0}@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){.page-header .sticky-menu.active .header-panel-bottom{padding:0 250px 0 0;border:0}.page-header .sticky-menu.active .logo{display:none}}@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){.page-header .sticky-menu.active{padding:0 10px;background-color:#13484e;color:#fff;background:#13484e url(../../../../codazon/themelayout/images/tspr.png) 0 0;min-height:50px}}
```

this is the code in header css.